# ErrorException: imagecreatefromstring(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG

Tags: php, gd, libjpeg

This is the error:

> ErrorException: imagecreatefromstring(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG

There are a lot of duplicates here on SO for exactly this problem, but none of the solutions solve my problem. Mainly it is advised to set

> gd.jpeg_ignore_warning=1

but this is already the default (I checked with phpinfo)

Also I cannot suppress this error by "@", since it is a full blow ErrorException

Can anybody help?

Thank you!

PS: The jpegs I am trying to load originated from my Samsung Galaxy S7

Comment: Seems like it's a known bugg: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72404. It's strange that according to others, setting `gd.jpeg_ignore_warning` to true did solve it, though. Just to be sure, try setting it in your code as well:  `ini_set( 'gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', true );`. What PHP version are you using?

Comment: I am using php 7.2.4, using ini_set does not solve the problem... and yes, I think it was the front camera! (like described in the bug) --- also, I do not get a warning, that I could just ignore: I am getting an ErrorException

Comment: Reading [this blog post](https://why-cant-we-have-nice-things.mwl.be/requests/exceptions-in-the-engine-for-php-7), they say: _"The E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR error type behaves like a fatal error by default, but it will invoke the error handler, which can instruct the engine to ignore the error and continue execution in the context where the error was raised."_. I guess that's why the "ignore_warning" no longer works. Have you tried if it works with image magick instead of GD? It might not be any difference, but doesn't hurt to try?

Comment: yes everything works fine with Imagick. Thanks for the hint. Now I feel stupid for working with gd for all those years :-)

Comment: Ah. Cool! Hehe. GD usually does the trick :-) It's rather Samsung that seem to be doing something weird.